# android device to device communication using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, communication

I want to create a android application that allows to people to send a simple message to a contact.

I don't want to make a instant messaging app, but want the user to be able to send a small messages to another contact selected on the user list, using parse.

I would rather not use other services like Pubnub, because I have heard you can send messages using parse as a backend.

please could you provide a tutorial link or GitHub or just code to send message to contact.

Comment: This question is way too broad to answer here.  [Parse docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide) are your friend here.  I wouldn't recommend doing a messaging app using parse but if you really wanted to, you would need write some cloud code that sends out a push to appropriate user when message is sent.  So start by looking at relational data, cloud code and push notifications section if you really wanted to do this in parse.

Comment: what would you recommend to use

Comment: You can use standard google cloud messaging.  [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android) is also a really good service (owned by google) that you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

here is the tutorial link for parse:

https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Also this is something you can implement yourself using a server and Google Cloud Messaging. It's not too difficult to do.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/